# How do I save my data internally?

Tags: android, android-listview, save

I am trying to create a "To Do List" and I have everything complete, except for saving the data.  I am fairly new and wondering if anybody could show me how to accomplish saving data internally.

Here is my code:

Main_ToDoList.java

```
public class Main_ToDoList extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
private Button btnAdd;
private EditText et;
private ListView lv;
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

final Context context = this;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    btnAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addTaskBtn);
    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
    et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, list);

    // set the lv variable to your list in the xml
    lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    // set ListView item listener
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id)
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Confirm Delete");
            alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Sure you want to delete?");
            alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
            alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)
                {
                    adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(position));
                }
            });
            alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)
                {
                    dialogInterface.cancel();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });
}
public void onClick(View v)
{
    String input = et.getText().toString();
    if(input.length() > 0)
    {
        adapter.add(input);
        et.setText("");
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main__to_do_list, menu);
    return true;
} 
}
```

How would I go about saving the data I enter?  Thanks!

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: what data you want to save ?

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 ways to do this:
SharedPreferences
File
Database

If you want to store a lot of data than use dataBase, if you want to store let's say 10-30tasks you can use SharedPreferences, which is the fastest way.

In any case if you are familiar with writing/reading files it will be also good path, but can require more work.

Answer (score 0):

i had some thing similar, i wanted to store small amount of data but didnt want to use a content provider or file so i used SharePreferences.
( ps i used random number on the end of the key just to make it unique, but the user selected it later from a list so i know the value then )

```
SharedPreferences sp = this.getPreferences( Context.MODE_PRIVATE );
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
Random rand = new Random();
int randomNum = rand.nextInt( 1000 );
editor.putString( "EQUATION_KEY_" + String.valueOf( randomNum ), textToSave);
editor.commit();
```

Comment: Does sharedPreference allow you to create items dynamically?  Because this is a To Do List and every time a new value gets added I need to save it but I will also be deleting items from it. So I don't want items I deleted to show up

Comment: yeah, i also delete from the SharedPrefs using,  "editor.remove( KEY_TO_DELETE );"  where KEY_TO_DELETE is the key of the item that the user selected from a ListView

Comment: So to be clear, first i populate the shared prefs with the above code, then later all the shared prefs are presented to the user and they can select one of the saved values or they can delete them. The fact that the key is random doesnt matter to me as the user selects the item from the list at which point i get the key and then i can pass it to the remove function to delete it from the shared pref

Comment: I am trying to save my data. So first I add a couple items to the listview (this all occurs on same page) then when I close the app and restart it I want to be able to have the data I add still there.  Right now when I close the app, and restart it the data is gone.

Comment: I want to save the listview to sharedPreference onDestroy.  This way I can rewrite the data that is saved and don't have to worry about deleting from sharedPreference

Comment: Well i guess you  will have to do the above for all items in the onDestroy(), dont forget to call commit(), then on onCreate() repopulate the ListView  by getting all values from the SP using the shared pref function getAll

Answer (score 0):

You can Make One DatabaseHandler Class

```
        package com.connection;

         import java.io.File;
         import java.io.FileOutputStream;
         import java.io.IOException;
         import java.io.InputStream;
         import java.io.OutputStream;
         import java.util.ArrayList;
         import android.content.ContentValues;
         import android.content.Context;
          import android.database.Cursor;
         import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
         import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
         import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement;
            import android.util.Log;

        public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {



// ====================== String Variables ======================
// The Android's default system path of your application database.
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example/databases/"; // Package name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "test"; // Database Name

// ++++++++++++++++++++++ int Variables ++++++++++++++++++++++
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1; // Database Version

// = = = = = = = = = = = Other Variables = = = = = = = = = = ==
private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
private final Context myContext;
SQLiteDatabase db;





public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.myContext = context;



}
public void db_open()
{
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
}
/**
 * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own
 * database.
 * */
public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
    boolean dbExist = databaseExist();

    if (dbExist) {
        // do nothing - database already exist
    } else {
        // By calling this method and empty database will be created into
        // the default system path
        // of your application so we are gone a be able to overwrite that
        // database with our database.
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        try {
            copyDataBase(); // call method to copy database
            db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Mrthod to check database is exist or not
 * @return
 */
public boolean databaseExist()
{
    File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME);
    return dbFile.exists();
}

/**
 * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created
 * empty database in the system folder, from where it can be accessed and
 * handled. This is done by transfering bytestream.
 * */
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
    // Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;

    // Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    // Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}


/**
 * Close Database
 */
@Override
public synchronized void close() {



    if (myDataBase != null)
        myDataBase.close();
    super.close();
}

public void DB_close()
{
    if(db!=null)
        db.close();
}


/**
 * Method to add data

 */
public  boolean addData(int vno,String content1,String content2){
    boolean status=false;

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    String checkEntry = "select id from yourtable where id="+vno;// +"' AND userid="+userid;

    Cursor magazinecursor = db.rawQuery(checkEntry, null);
    if (magazinecursor.moveToFirst()) {

    } else {

        values.put("id", vno);
        values.put("content1", content1);
        values.put("content2", content2);




        long check = db.insert("yourtable", null, values);
        if (check > -1) {
            Log.i("inserstatus", "yourtable insert successfull");
            status = true;
        } else {
            Log.i("insertstatus", "yourtable insert unsuccessful");
        }
    }

    return status;
}





@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
```

}

And then in your Activity where you want to save data

```
              DatabaseHandler myDbHelper;

            myDbHelper = new DatabaseHandler(MainActivity.this);
            myDbHelper.db_open();
            myDbHelper.addData(1,"sample",sample);
```

Hope this will help you or other....

Comment: Sorry not using a database. I am more interested in sharedPreferences.